# Import an iOS framework (Swift/Objective-C) into an Android app project?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin

I'm working on an iOS application that will communicate with a Bluetooth device.

My manager wants me to do research to share logic code between the two platforms with Kotlin Native (I don't know Android development nor Kotlin, I only played with the project example on Kotlin Multiplatform documentation).

While I agree that sharing logic code is a great idea, I have some questions.

The application will use the shared code module that will itself communicate with a platform-specific Bluetooth wrapper.

1) How can I import the iOS Bluetooth wrapper in Kotlin so the shared module can use iOS Bluetooth? (I found that it is possible but didn't find any concrete example)

2) Besides, I'm wondering (as I'm the only mobile developer for the moment) if it is relevant to think about sharing code with Kotlin/Native now instead of going for a pure Swift module. What do you think?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Sharing code across iOS and Android apps using Kotlin Multiplatform is possible. Here is a [short recap](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mobilecrossplatform/) of its features.

Sharing business logic across platforms is a good idea (though I'm a little biased). You get less code with fewer bugs, guarantee the same behaviour on both platforms, while still having native UI.

Regarding your second question here are some relevant links:

- [An article](https://blog.molo17.com/2019/02/a-trip-into-kotlin-multiplatform-projects-part-2/) on writing cross-platform bluetooth module
- [BlueFalcon](https://github.com/Reedyuk/blue-falcon), multiplatform bluetooth library

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't mix the two platforms. If you really would like to share code between android and ios you should write it in C. Both platforms can handle native C codes.